# mvm quarkus:dev now has commandline interactive interface how can I turn it off?

Tags: maven, terminal, quarkus

I run quarkus using the command

```
mvn quarkus:dev
```

In the past this was fine but now the output is interspersed with an interactive curses based menu like below :

```
Tests paused
Press [r] to resume testing, [o] Toggle test output, [h] for more options>
```

I am spawning several quarkus processes at one time and redirecting the output into a UI I created to aggregate the output so I'm not flipping back and forth between 7 terminal windows.  The recent introduction of this "feature" apparently causes the normal output  to either be redirected directly to the tty because the redirection of stderr/stdout is no logger being picked up by my application. How can I remove this feature from quarkus:dev ?

Comment: It's unlikely to be using curses (or relevant to Linux in particular) if it's a Java application as described.  If you have specific packaging information demonstrating this, it should be part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mvn quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.console.enabled='false'`

Comment: Worked like a charm Thank You!